# Should Endmembers be Normalized for Linear Unmixing?

Tags: remote-sensing

In biological spectral microscopy, the standard in the field is to use normalized endmembers in linear unmixing algorithms.  In most cases, the endmembers are normalized to the maximum value.  I have not found a reference that explains why endmembers are normalized prior to linear unmixing.  By normalizing, are we not removing information about relative intensity of objects?

I am asking my question here because I am curious if endmember normalization is routine in remote sensing as well.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about geographic information systems within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: You could consult statisticians which work in biology related disciplines.